# Issue when adding charts pod

Tags: swift3, cocoapods

I am new in swift and I am trying to add Charts pod using -

```
pod 'Charts', :git=> 'https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git'
```

And I am getting following issues after adding Charts pod

```
.../Pods/Charts/Source/Charts/Charts/BarLineChartViewBase.swift:75:76: Cannot use instance member '_viewPortHandler' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
.../Pods/Charts/Source/Charts/Charts/BarLineChartViewBase.swift:79:77: Cannot use instance member '_viewPortHandler' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
.../Pods/Charts/Source/Charts/Charts/BarLineChartViewBase.swift:86:72: Cannot use instance member '_viewPortHandler' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
.../Pods/Charts/Source/Charts/Components/AxisBase.swift:137:24: 'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion
```

I am using swift 3 and Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Charts seem to support Swift 4.1. You need a version that supports Swift 3.1, which is what Xcode 8 has.

According to the version history, Charts 3.0.2 supports Swift 3.1, so you should install that version:

```
pod 'Charts', '3.0.2'
```

Do a `pod install` after that.

Obviously, you can also choose to update to Xcode 9 and Swift 4.

Comment: 3.0.3 will not work in this case.  He is on XCode 8.3, not 9

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Oops! It's a typo... I wrote 3.0.2 a line above the code block. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper for your answer. I understood the issue but pod 'Charts', '~> 3.0.2' not working. It's still using still using 3.0.5 when I try to update or install pod.

Comment: @Sweeper I am accepting the answer as it solved the issue. Can you have a look at a new issue I am facing now -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767947/charts-pod-not-downgrading

Answer (score 1):

Given you are using Swift 3, Xcode 8.3, you'll have to install an older release of Charts.  The various releases can be found on the menu bar under releases:

[image]

I believe this release should install properly:
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/releases/tag/v3.0.2

Comment: I had set the platfom to ios 9.0 and I was using pod 'Charts' before I found this https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2332

Comment: I am bit confused. Do I need Xcode 9.3 / Swift 4.1 as stated here https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts

Comment: I'll update my answer.  It is your version of Xcode/Swift that is the issue.