# Charts Pod not downgrading

Tags: swift3, cocoapods

I am using Xcode 8.3 and swift 3. In order to use charts library, I need to use Charts 3.0.2 but Cocoapods is always installing the latest library.

I tried following commands -

```
pod install
pod update
```

but none are working. Here is the screenshot 
[image]

Comment: Try removing the line from podfile, pod install, add it back again, and pod install again.

Comment: I tried that otherwise, it would have shown 'using Charts (3.0.5)' instead of installing Charts(3.0.5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By trial and error, I figured out that removing the `~>` thingy works, so now your line will look like:

```
pod 'Charts', '3.0.2'
```

And then you need a `pod update`, and this will show up:

```
Installing Charts 3.0.2 (was 3.0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper. It worked but do you have any idea what ~> this thing means or what its called.

Comment: @Shubh See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213751/what-is-the-usage-of-in-cocoapods

Comment: @Sergio This is not Xcode's fault. This is due to cocoa pod's design.

Comment: Yes but I need to use it for xcode. And it has to be an older version of xcode so I can compile an older project.... not fun.